# Responsive Images Warping

Tags: css, responsive, images

I'm using HB Themes Aegaeus theme and it's great except for the fact that one of the shortcode elements (hb-box) is resizing the images.

(Obviously, automatically resizing site elements to fit a mobile device is one of the main reasons to use responsive design, but in this instance, it makes the image subjects look really, REALLY bad.)

http://www.fullyhr.com/about/

[image]

**How do I maintain the image size-ratio?**

This is the shortcode for the images in question **on the page**:

```
[hb_image_box image="http://fullyhr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/headshot_l_amanda.jpg"     link="http://fullyhr.com/portfolio/amanda-mayo-sphr/"
title="Amanda Mayo" subtitle="SPHR, Founder, Sr HR Consultant"]
```

I have already tried the following custom css solutions:

```
.custom-hb-box { width: 100% !important; display:block; height: auto !important; }

.custom-hb-box img { height: auto !important; width: 100% !important; }
```

However, these make the site time out with a "Website Not Available" error.

UPDATE 
Here is the shortcode **from the theme-shortcodes.php file:**

```
function hb_custom_box($atts, $content = null){

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'title' =>'Title here', 
    'subtitle' => 'Subtitle here',
    'image' =>'',
    'link' =>'http://'
), $atts));

$image = hb_resize(null, $image, 460, 400, true);
$image = $image['url'];
$output = "
<div>
    <a href='$link' class='custom-hb-box'>
        <img src='$image' rel='Image'>

    <div class='hb-custom-title'>
        <span class='titt'>$title</span>
        <span class='subtitt'>$subtitle</span>
    </div>

    <div class='hb-custom-glare'></div>
    </a>
</div>";

return $output;
}
add_shortcode('hb_image_box', 'hb_custom_box');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to know what your CSS properties are doing without seeing the related HTML.  I would use the max-width property instead of width `img{ max-width: 100%; }`.

UPDATE:
I just noticed you provided a link.  The height property is a problem:

```
.custom-hb-box img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Setting '.custom-hb-box img {height: auto; } seems to solve the image issue but you have problems with the text as well.

```
#main-content-with-sidebar .custom-hb-box {
    height: 205px !important;
    width: 33% !important;
}
```

Explicit pixel height won't work.  It looks like this is being done to compensate for the fact that the images do not have the desired aspect ratio.  Resize your images to have a ratio of 211:205, this will match the container element.

Then try

```
#main-content-with-sidebar .custom-hb-box {
    height: auto;
}
```

Or just remove the height property in the above rule; it really isn't needed.

Comment: hmm. I'm trying these suggestions, but am having just some sort of disconnect. Whenever I try to add any custom css, my mobile connection to the webpage completely breaks. I am looking for more info.

Comment: I can't comment on why CSS changes would break the mobile site.  But, I did notice in the update code you posted" `$image = hb_resize(null, $image, 460, 400, true);`.  So, it looks like your will be forced to use the given image ratio.  Does your theme support child themes?  If it does, you might want to write your own version of that code.

Comment: Yeah, that's the section that caught my eye, too. nuts. I will look into a child theme and post whether it works out. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed the your style,css file is minimized.  Are you trying to edit the minimized version, or are do you have a readable version that you then minimize after editing?

Comment: http://documentation.hb-themes.com/aegaeus/#useChildTheme

Comment: ok, I swear I am not a complete n00b, I've been doing this for quite a while, but I have not yet touched the style.css file. I've been working entirely within the WordPress CMS - I did make edits to the shortcode.php file within the WordPress theme editor section. I am trying to open the style.css file from my Cyberduck/Dreamweaver applications and can't connect to the server, which is really out of the ordinary, so I'm working on that problem now. garble grr.

Comment: Also, thanks for the child theme recommendation. I'm looking at that, but it's not something I usually choose to do - it looks like I'll have to recreate the entire site, correct? That feels extreme for such a small display issue. I'll have to research how much work that'll really involve and clear it with the client.

Comment: A child theme is always desirable if customization is required.  I don't see why the site needs to be recreated but that might be a way for you to get back to square 1.  Did you receive my email?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Because of all my comments to BillK's suggestions, I just wanted to provide clarification that I WAS able to fix this issue.

Instead of adding css in the Custom CSS field in Highend Options > General Settings (as suggested by the theme developer), I quit dinking around within WordPress and logged directly into the server to edit the css there.

Here is the server file path:

wp-content > themes > Aegaeus > css > styles.css

**Near the bottom is this bit:**

```
#main-content-with-sidebar .custom-hb-box{width:33%!important;height:205px!important}
```

**Change it to this:**

```
#main-content-with-sidebar .custom-hb-box{height:auto;}
```

and voila! It’s fixed. Thanks, BillK! (Please vote for his answer, it's all there!)